# アソシエーションでバリデーションしつつメッセージを変更する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

受け取った user_id が FK として存在してるかバリデーションしたいのですが

```
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id 
  validates :user, presence: { message: 'エラーテスト' }
```

とかいてしまうと form からは user_id というキーでパラメータが飛んでくるのでフォームの色が変わってくれません

```
  validates :user_id, presence: true, if: -> { user.present? }
```

とかけばバリデーションはうまくいくのですがさらにメッセージを変えるにはどうすればいいんでしょうか

```
  validates :user_id, presence: { message: 'エラーテスト' }, if: -> { user.present? }
```

と書いてしまうと存在しないFKも保存されてしまいバリデーションがうまく行きません

FKによるバリデーションはこちらを参考にしました
https://qiita.com/ledsun/items/25823f5addc41459b6b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

スマートな方法かはわからないですが
カスタムバリデーションを使えば何とでもなると思います

```
validate present_user

def present_user
  errors.add(:user_id, :user_not_exists) if users.nil?
end
```